# UV4L on RPI WebRTC with Janus Gateway ICE error

Tags: raspberry-pi, webrtc, video4linux, janus-gateway

I need to stream from the RPI Camera to a Janus room with webrtc.
I installed UV4L on my PI, and try the demo with the gateway url https://janus.conf.meetecho.com : it's work.

I installed janus-gateway on a server (demos here : https://janus.kizbat.com)
And the gateway url is : janus.kizbat.com:8089
Janus camera room work very well with browsers (chrome from my computer), but when I try to connect with uv4L on the pi I get this error on the janus log :

```
[3157879423705975] Creating ICE agent (ICE Full mode, controlled)
[WARN] [3157879423705975] Skipping disabled/unsupported media line...
[ERR] [ice.c:janus_ice_cb_component_state_changed:1473][3157879423705975] ICE failed for component 1 in stream 1...
No WebRTC media anymore
Detaching handle from JANUS VideoRoom plugin
No WebRTC media anymore
Cleaning up handle 3157879423705975...
```

I tried to setup a STUN/TURN server, but I get the same error.

Do you have an idea ?

Comment: Make sure Janus is compiled with data channel support.

Comment: @cylwin have you solved this issue? I'm facing the exact same problem

Comment: Hi @cylwin

How did u solve this issue.

firstly could u tell me how to stream rpi through the default janus coinference url, Im getting : 
 <warning> [server] Missing mandatory element (admin_key)
 in the RPi uv4l_raspicam.service logs.